# My Apostrophe Key is Making Commas

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard, input-languages, input

While using MS Word in Windows 7, when I type the <kbd>`</kbd> key and if it's not at the end of a word, it turns into a <kbd>,</kbd>.

I've never had this issue before and it's driving me crazy! I tried googling it to limited results, my region is indeed set to English-US, not the international version so I'm not sure what gives.

Comment: Might check your AutoCorrect settings for an entry for ' to be replaced with  a comma.  Not sure how it would get in there, but AutoCorrect sounds like your culprit at first glance (File/Office Icon -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options -> AutoCorrect tab)

Comment: I'm seeing [a microsoft Q&A](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-2010-quotation-marks-appearing-at-the-bottom/3c03bae8-234d-4a80-975d-a12eac5d7acc) that seems relevant.

Comment: zzzzBov, that did it! I think I know what happened now, the proofing language within Word was set to German. I suspect that must be what the person who sent be the file has their default as and my system just went with it.

Comment: @zzzzBov - thanks also from me! That did it - also a German proofing language issue O.o perhaps worthwhile making an answer out of this comment!